# Is there any option to minimize this elastic search must not match query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to avoid some text from the field and for that I have used must not condition but, it seems to be static also took more lines. So, please let me know is there any other option to optimize this query.

Here is the query,

```
"must_not": [
    {
    "match": {
    "field.keyword": "welcome"
        }
    },
    {
    "match": {
    "field.keyword": "Welcome"
        }    
    },
    {
    "match": {
    "field.keyword": "entry_point"
        }
    },
    {
    "match": {
    "field.keyword": "Entry point"
        }
    }
    ]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Since you are doing exact match(keyword), you can use terms query

Comment: How is this (relevantly) related to Python?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal any example you can refer me to?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match? or you want to exclude all sentences with the word welcome?

Comment: @KlausD. because python is server side programming and nowadays most of them were using Elastic search with Python and that is the reason I have added python tag as well.

Comment: @tomslabbaert You're right I just want to exclude all the sentences which is not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If search text is same , you can use [multi- match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) which will search for text in multiple fields

```
"bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
         "multi_match": {
           "query": "text",
           "fields": ["field1.keyword","field2.keyword"]
         }
        }
      ]
    }
```

If  field is same and texts are different , you can use terms query

```
"must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "field.keyword": [
              "VALUE1",
              "VALUE2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

If both fields and texts are different you will have to use query in your question.

Comment: Thanks @jaspreet chahal let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are not looking for an exact match i would just use [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) for single words and [match phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) for phrases.

```
"must_not": [
    { 
       "query_string": {
            "query": "welcome OR Welcome"
        }
    },
    {
       "match_phrase": {
          "title": {
             "query": "entry point",
          }
       }
   }
 ]
```

I'm not sure which analyzer you use but if you use lowercase + alphanumeric only for example you wont have to have "duplicate" queries like "welcome" and "Welcome".